# Iterating multiple items of different sizes in JSTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, jstl

My JSP page is receiving two lists: One is the list of all autorizations available and the other is the autorizations availables for one specific user. I want create a list of checkbox where all the autorizations are listed, but only the autorizations of the user are checked. Someone can point me one direction for do this?

**UPDATE 1**

this is the html/jstl code to display ALL the autorizations:

```
<div class="row" id="autorizacoes ${item.id}">
            <c:forEach var="item_auth" items="${autorizacoes}">
                <input type="checkbox" name="${item_auth.nome}" onclick="mudaAutorizacao(${item_auth.nome})">${item_auth.nome}
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
```

the page where this code is included is invoked by this method (placed in my controller):

```
@RequestMapping("/listagem_usuario")
    public ModelAndView listagem_usuario()
    {
        UsuarioDAO lista = new UsuarioDAO();
        DadosDAO dados = new DadosDAO();
        TipoDAO tipo = new TipoDAO();
        AutorizacaoDAO auth = new AutorizacaoDAO();

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("listagem_usuario");
        mav.addObject("usuarios", lista.lista());
        mav.addObject("campos", dados.getListaCampos());
        mav.addObject("tipos", tipo.getListaTipos());
        mav.addObject("autorizacoes", auth.getListaAutorizacoes());

        return mav;
    }
```

that is the method from AutorizationDAO which read the autorizations from the database:

```
public List<Autorizacao_usuario> getListaAutorizacoes()
    {
        List<Autorizacao_usuario> lista = new ArrayList<Autorizacao_usuario>();

        conecta();

        if(executa("SELECT id, nome, descricao FROM autorizacoes;")) {
            do{
                Autorizacao_usuario auth = new Autorizacao_usuario(getInt(1), getString(2), getString(3));
                lista.add(auth);
            }while(proximo());
        }

        return lista;
    }
```

the autorizations of each user are available from this `List<Autorizacao_usuario> getAutorizacoes()` (of the class com.HorarioLivre.core.Usuario):

and, finally, this is the POJO class that keeps the autorization data in memory:

```
package com.HorarioLivre.core;

public class Autorizacao_usuario {
    private int Id;

    private String nome;

    private String descricao;

    public Autorizacao_usuario()
    {
        this.setId(0);
        this.setNome(null);
        this.setDescricao(null);
    }

    public Autorizacao_usuario(int id, String nome, String descricao)
    {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setNome(nome);
        this.setDescricao(descricao);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public String setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
        return descricao;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do your lists work? How can one compare which item is on both lists? Show some of your code please.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. code included now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<div class="row" id="autorizacoes ${item.id}">
        <c:forEach var="item_auth" items="${autorizacoes}">
            <c:set var="isChecked" value="${false}"/>
            <c:forEach var="user_auth" items="${userAutorizacoes}">
                <c:if test="${user_auth.id == item_auth.id}">  <!-- here compare according ID or any unique attribute -->
                    <c:set var="isChecked" value="${true}"/>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
            <input type="checkbox" name="${item_auth.nome}" onclick="mudaAutorizacao(${item_auth.nome})"  <c:if test="${isChecked}">checked="checked"</c:if> />${item_auth.nome}
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

It checks for each `item_auth` if it equals to autorizations of the user and if so it sets checked attribute in the checkbox element.